# Loading screen in Angular 2

Tags: angular

I'd like to implement pre-bootstrap loading screen in Angular2 project. I found several samples for Angular1. For example, this one:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>
    Creating A Pre-Bootstrap Loading Screen In AngularJS
</title>
</head>
<body ng-controller="AppController">
<div class="m-app-loading" ng-animate-children>
    <style type="text/css">
        some styling...
    </style>
    <!-- BEGIN: Actual animated container. -->
    <div class="animated-container">
        <div class="messaging">
            <h1>
                App is Loading
            </h1>
            <p>
                Please stand by for your ticket to awesome-town!
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- END: Actual animated container. -->
</div>
<!-- END: App-Loading Screen. -->
<h1>
    Creating A Pre-Bootstrap Loading Screen In AngularJS
</h1>
<p>
    You have {{ friends.length }} friends:
</p>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        {{ friend }}
    </li>
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/angularjs/angular-1.3.8.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../vendor/angularjs/angular-animate-1.3.8.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var app = angular.module( "Demo", [ "ngAnimate" ] );
    setTimeout(
        function asyncBootstrap() {
            angular.bootstrap( document, [ "Demo" ] );
        },
        ( 2 * 1000 )
        );
    app.controller(
        "AppController",
        function( $scope ) {
            console.log( "App Loaded!", $scope );
            $scope.friends = [ "Kim", "Sarah", "Tricia" ];
        }
        );
    app.directive(
        "mAppLoading",
        function( $animate ) {
            return({
                link: link,
                restrict: "C"
            });
            function link( scope, element, attributes ) {
                $animate.leave( element.children().eq( 1 ) ).then(
                    function cleanupAfterAnimation() {
                        element.remove();
                        scope = element = attributes = null;
                    }
                    );
            }
        }
        );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a [demo](http://bennadel.github.io/JavaScript-Demos/demos/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-angularjs/). I'm getting in trouble because I've started learning Angular 2 recently, and don't know Angular 1. How to "convert" this JS code to TS? Thanks!

Comment: JS code almost every time is a valid TS code. It's not about converting JS to TS. It's rather about converting angular to angular 2.

Comment: you have a similar question here and solution provided by me here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243443/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-for-angular2/44227064#44227064

Comment: solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243443/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-for-angular2/44227064#44227064

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing here related to TypeScript. Simply add your loading content within the main component within your `index.html` page. When the component will be evaluated by Angular2, this content will be replaced by the one from the component template.

Here is a sample content of an `index.html` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <title>Angular 2 app</title>
    <script src="/lib/system.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/router.dev.js"></script>
    <script src="/lib/http.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        (...)
      });
      System.import('src/boot')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
  </body>
</html>
```

In this case, `<my-app>` simply corresponds to the main component of your application, the one you provide to the `bootstrap` function:

```
import {MyApp} from './my-app';

bootstrap(MyApp, []);
```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: Dang , felt stupid now.. tried all kinds of *ngIf="false" etc etc but of course that didn't work.. your suggestion did.. thanks again

Comment: I am facing the same requirement (Angular2 loading screen) Can you share a complete example on how you got this working? Thanks

Comment: In fact, everything is there ;-) If you're interested you could have a look at this sample: https://github.com/restlet/restlet-sample-angular2 and the corresponding article: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/30/implementing-an-angular-2-frontend-over-an-apispark-hosted-web-api-part-1/

Comment: I know this is an old question, but I can't figure out how to style it a bit more. I would like a full screen thing, but in order to do that I would have to style the `body`, `html` and even the `my-app` element. Is that a normal solution?