# Pre-bootstrap loading screen

Tags: angular

I'm looking for a pre-bootstrap loading screen along the lines of [this example](http://bennadel.github.io/JavaScript-Demos/demos/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-angularjs/) but for Angular 2.

Answer (score 84):

I can suggest a simple CSS approach.

First of all add `.loading` div into main HTML page, it should follow main app component element. For example:

```html
<my-app></my-app>

<div class="loading">
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>
```

Now you can target and style splash screen with `my-app:empty + .loading` CSS selector, and make it disappear as soon as the app gets bootstraped. Example:

```css
/* default .loading styles, .loading should be invisible, opacity: 0, z-index: -1 */
.loading {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #000;
    z-index: -1;
}
/* .loading screen is visible when app is not bootstrapped yet, my-app is empty */
my-app:empty + .loading {
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

This approach works better if you put all heavy scripts before closing body tag and leave just minimal styles necessary to the loading screen in the head so it shows up as soon as possible and then scripts start to load.

Here is a simple demo:

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/v8FtkSluRDSrkcq4v7a1?p=preview

Comment: Hey @dfsq, your solution works for the first time the page is loaded. However when there are multiple components loaded via RouteConfig (which causes the browser window to "jump" with static content first) I'm back to the initial problem.


That's why I'm thinking that the full solution here is to use ng animate for full integration with the bootstrap as well as subsequent loading for other components.

Any ideas as to how to solve this problem in a pure CSS approach?

Comment: This is too complicated. You can simplify the approach by wrapping into <app></app> what needs to be displayed on a splashscreen: e.g. <app>Loading...</app> and that's all. Angular will automatically replace "Loading..." by the real content once Angular is loaded. Keep also in mind that the aim of a splashscreen is to be displayed before Angular is loaded. For this reason, ngAnimate or anything Angular specific will not work - or will work just too late... Regarding your application which "jumps", you should probably find out first where you want to go before displaying anything.

Comment: @ChristopheVidal The problem with what you are suggesting and why I decided not to go this way in my answer (I tried this obvious approach first) is that you won't be able to use CSS transitions in this case. If static splash screen is all you need, then of course it is better. My solution is more generic.

Comment: Definitely, the approach you use is smart when such transitions are required. But I just wanted to point out that adding a splashscreen (possibly with animations but without transitions) is in angular2 very straightforward.

Comment: In place of opacity transition, you can use transition delay to prevent blank between `my-app` is no empty anymore by is no completely loaded : `transition: opacity 0 ease-in-out 1s;`

Comment: This doesn't work in IE11. The loading screen remains in the foreground until user clicks the screen with the mouse

Comment: even I face similar issues as @netlander , while loading the app solution works nicely. I am showing static content like terms&condition  inside an iframe in one of my components. I am loading this component from <a [routerLink]="'/terms-and-conditions">, Here the problem is after clicking on the link app is flickering and showing previously displayed component inside the same component. Please let me know if you had found the solution

Comment: @RahulUpadhyay It would help if you could provide stackblitz demo to replicate the issue to troubleshoot?

Comment: @dfsq I investigated more and found out, whenever iframe src URL is invalid that time, loading iframe component from footer link reloading the app and that's ending up showing the loader again.

Answer (score 20):

I went with a simple approach (I did like the other answer though too) using FontAwesome spinners:

```
<app-root>
    <div class="text-center">
        <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
        <div>Something witty for your userbase</div>
    </div>
</app-root>
```

Comment: Hi, did you find that this loading spinner doesn't show on mobile? I did this and mobile never shows it. I get white screen then the app shows. Did you do anything to get around this?

Comment: It seems to work for me on iPad and Android - note:  There is a delay in the beginning before anything is loaded and then this spinner appears until the whole SPA is loaded. What mobile/OS are you using?

Comment: This approach cause 1 second of a blank page when using lazy loading

Answer (score 9):

Why not try this approach:

```
<app-root>
    <style type="text/css">
        #pre-bootstrap {
            background-color: #262626;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            position: fixed;
            right: 0px;
            top: 0px;
            z-index: 999999;
        }

        #pre-bootstrap div.messaging {
            color: #FFFFFF;
            font-family: monospace;
            left: 0px;
            margin-top: -37px;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0px;
            text-align: center;
            top: 50%;
        }

        #pre-bootstrap h1 {
            font-size: 26px;
            line-height: 35px;
            margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
        }

        #pre-bootstrap p {
            font-size: 18px;
            line-height: 14px;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
  </style>

  <div id="pre-bootstrap">
    <div class="messaging">
        <h1>
            App is Loading
        </h1>

        <p>
            Please stand by for your ticket to awesome-town!
        </p>

      </div>
   </div>
</app-root>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">
    app-root:empty::after {
      content: 'Loading…';
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      font-size: 20px;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Very simple approach. And of course you can replace text with loader image.

Answer (score 0):

i guess the best approach is to have the inline style in the loading div HTML (to show). Then in css you have a class to hide and use the ngOnInit to include that class in the loading div.

In that case we will have the html rendering the style first.. showing the loading and after all (download css and run js) it will have the class that hides it.

```js
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public loaded=false;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loaded=true;
  }
 }
```

```css
 .loading.loaded {
     z-index: -1;
     opacity: 0;
  }
```

```html
<div class="loading" 

    style="opacity: 0.9;
       color: #EEE;
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
      transition: opacity .8s ease-in-out;
      height: 100%;
      background: #fff;
      z-index: 100;
      display: table;"
      
  [class.loaded]="loaded">
  
      <md-spinner 
        style="display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;"
        ></md-spinner>
        
  </div>
```

I had to take out the visibility of the components inside the angular view, because they were loaded without any style when load (like a flickr without style). So in css i hide and in the app.html i show

```css
footer, header, home-view, homebuyer-view, homeseller-view, homecommerce-view,
.mat-select-placeholder{
  visibility: hidden !important;
}
```

```html
<style *ngIf="loaded">
  footer, header,home-view, homebuyer-view, homeseller-view, homecommerce-view,
  .mat-select-placeholder{
          visibility: visible !important;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

All what you need for add splash screen in Angular project is tow step:

1- Add this CSS code into ***head*** tag  of **index.html**:

```
<style>
    .splash {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      transition: opacity 1.4s ease-in-out, visibility 1.4s;
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #1e85c8;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    app-root:not(:empty) + .splash {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .splash_image {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 200px;
    }
  </style>
```

2- Then add this HTML lines into app-root selector:

```
  <div class="splash">
    <img class="splash_image" src="assets/images/logo.svg" alt="" />
  </div>
```

Note: Change **src** for valid logo path...

In this way, loader will auto disappear when Angular set content of app-root, I think this best way for splash screen in Angular.

---

**Full code** of index.html file will be like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Project Title</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

  <style>
    .splash {
      opacity: 1;
      z-index: 1;
      visibility: visible;
      transition: opacity 1.4s ease-in-out, visibility 1.4s;
      position: fixed;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
      top: 0;
      left: 0;
      background: #1e85c8;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
    }
    app-root:not(:empty) + .splash {
      opacity: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    .splash_image {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 200px;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
<app-root>
  <div class="splash">
    <img class="splash_image" src="assets/images/logo.svg" alt="" />
  </div>
</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```