# Some questions on what to do while an Angular 2 application is loading

Tags: jquery, angular, angular-cli, angular-material2

I am using the `angular-cli` to create an Angular 2 application. After the application is created with `ng new NEW_PROJECTNAME`, we get a `index.html` page. In this page they have something like this.

```
...
<body>
 <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
 ...
</body>
```

Needless to say, this loading message may appear wholly unprofessional. So my question is how do I add something more appropriate like a progress bar or spinner?

I realize that what needs to happen is happening all outside of the Angular framework (right?). I found some Angular 2 packages that would be very good to use (e.g. [Angular 2 material](https://github.com/angular/material2) or the [ng2-slim-loading-bar](https://github.com/akserg/ng2-slim-loading-bar)), but these packages assume I have already entered the Angular framework; meaning I'm inside some Angular component.

So my questions are as follows.

- Is there an Angular 2 hook that I can use to show a loading indicator before content is placed in `<app-root></app-root>`?
- If I have to work outside of the Angular framework, what would be the best approach? Naively, I'd envision I'd have to install some package with `bower` or `npm`, reference that in `index.html`, and use `jQuery` or something to show the loading indicator. I assume by the time Angular is done loading, it'll replace whatever is inside `<app-root></app-root>`. One of my concerns with this approach is the building/packaging scripts (I'd then have to figure out how to include this bower/npm package with my built application).

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to put a CSS animation inside the app bootstrap component when the app is ready the content will be replaced.

Note that the app will load at different speeds depending on whether it is a development build or a production build, because of the minification of the scripts and the change detection will run only once, giving faster loading times.
You might need to adjust the speed of the animation.
Http requests from the app may also play a role.

I got this from: http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/css3-loading-animation/

CSS and Html in the root component:

```
  <app-root>

  <style>
    #content {
      width: 100%;
      /* Full Width */
      height: 1px;
      margin: 1px auto;
      background: #000;
    }

    .expand {
      width: 100%;
      height: 1px;
      margin: 1px 0;
      background: #2187e7;
      position: absolute;
      box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 1px rgba(0, 198, 255, 0.7);

                 /*adjust speed here */
      -moz-animation: fullexpand 1.5s ease-out;
      -webkit-animation: fullexpand 1.5s ease-out;
    }


    /* Full Width Animation Bar */

    @-moz-keyframes fullexpand {
      0% {
        width: 0px;
      }
      100% {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }

    @-webkit-keyframes fullexpand {
      0% {
        width: 0px;
      }
      100% {
        width: 100%;
      }
      ;
    }
  </style>

    <div id="content">
      <span class="expand">Loading...</span>
    </div>


  </app-root>
```

The second option is to access the `bootstrap` functionality trough `system.js` and make it available for script tags in `index.html`.

Here is a blog post by [Ben Nadel](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/3105-creating-a-pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-in-angular-2-rc-1.htm) no How to do that.

Demo: [Creating A Pre-Bootstrap Loading Screen In Angular 2 RC 1](http://bennadel.github.io/JavaScript-Demos/demos/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-angular2/)

```
(function( global ) {

    // .... code removed ....

    System.config({
        // .... code removed ....
    });

    // Load "./app/main.ts" (gets full path from package configuration above).
    // --
    // NOTE: We are attaching the resultant promise to the global scope so that other
    // scripts may listen for the successful loading of the application.
    global.bootstrapping = System
        .import( "app" )
        .then(
            function handleResolve() {

                console.info( "System.js successfully bootstrapped app." );

            },
            function handleReject( error ) {

                console.warn( "System.js could not bootstrap the app." );
                console.error( error );

                return( Promise.reject( error ) );

            }
        )
    ;

})( window );
```

Comment: Ben Nadel, published an updated solution in his blog. Check it out here - https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3147-creating-an-event-driven-pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-in-angular-2-0-0.htm. However, I still don't understand all that fuss with DOM events and heaps of JavaScript code, that's why I go with a simple solution published here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/35244932/968003.

Answer (score 0):

I went for a simple approach with FontAwesome and Bootstrap:

```
  <app-root>
        <div class="text-center">
            <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
            <div>Something witty</div>
        </div>
    </app-root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found any hook for our stack (Webpack). You might possibly append some arbitrary JavaScript code at the end of each module (if you use them) hich would increment some counter. WebPack's [loaders API](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/)  could be used for that. (Applies only if you use WebPack of course.)

In our project, used @Kaspars' solution to mimic the application which is loading, i.e. visually similar page, with alogo, a spinner, and some information to keep the user busy reading it until the app loads.