# angular 2 loading screen spinner

Tags: css, angular, loading

WHats the canonical way to show loading [nice spinner](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/) while angular 2 is loading instead of `<app>Loading...</app>` text?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243443/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-for-angular2/35244932#35244932

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pre-Bootstrap Loading Screen For Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243443/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-for-angular2)