# Loading screen inside router outlet before lazy loaded module is initialized Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

I'm trying to display loading screen inside router outlet till data is received.

here is my code inside index.html

```
 <root>
  <div class="app-content text-center">
    <div class="app-content-body" >
      <div class="loader_div" >
        <div class="loader"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
 </root>
```

which works as expected but as I try to execute same code inside  It remains Inside the screen even after the screen Is loaded.

One possible solution is that I can subscribe in router event and use instanceof NavigationStart and NavigationEnd.and use ngIf to remove the DOM from routeroutlet.

Is there any other easier way to solve that?

Edit1: After subscribing in router event I realized it wasn't wise decision. Because in case more than one nested router-outlet It'll show refresh screen in whole page instead of the part where the child router-outlet is located.
When I inspect DOM, `<ng-component>` doesn't replace `<router-outlet>` instead it's loaded after finishing tag.(`</router-outlet>`)
Is it a bug of Angular2?

Comment: Where exactly is `<router-outlet>` in your code?

Comment: @AngularFrance I used it in multiple place. In most complex structure I'm using 3 nested '<router-outlet>'. and I want to show the loader of only last child when the code inside the last child is loaded.

Comment: `Is it a bug of Angular2?` no. You can use sibling css selector. like `router + .loading { opacity: 1 }` See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243443/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-for-angular2