# Angular2 Spinner on startup

Tags: angular

From many angular 2 examples, we see this code in index.html:

```
<app>loading</app>
```

This is to tell user that the application JavaScripts are not here in the browser yet, so for now the browser just load this "loading" text

I wonder how we can change this text be an actual spinner component. That is, how to show a spinner component when browser is still loading the application JavaScripts?

(An example of the final result would be what  u see when u visit LinkedIn.com.  Before you see all the contents loaded, u first just see all these empty boxes flashing.)

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243443/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-for-angular2

Comment: you could use a font-awesome spinner https://www.w3schools.com/icons/fontawesome_icons_spinner.asp

Comment: do you want a spinner for each page load also or just for landing page loading ?

Comment: You could use a spinner of font-awesome. FA is a css library which could be loaded before the whole Angular app.

Comment: Thanks guys. I actually thought there could be a way to send some small part of angular(the spinner) before bootstrap to the browser. I guess there isn't really a way to do this? so we have to use pure html-css as workarounds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I do is simply show a spinner gif centered on the screen. You could use a font-awesome spinner as @JonathanNiu mentioned, or any other icon/image really...

```
<body>
    <my-app>
      <div class="loading-app">
            <img src="./public/img/spin.gif" />
      </div>
    </my-app>
</body>
```

and the css class, which sits in my global styles file:

```
.loading-app {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
```