# Angular 5 Loading Spinner on Startup with Lazy-Loaded Route/Module

Tags: angular, spinner, lazy-loading, angular-router, angular-module

In Angular 5, how can I show a [loading spinner](http://tobiasahlin.com/spinkit/) on **app startup** if the requested route/module is **lazy loaded**?

My first idea was to simply include the spinner code inside the `<app-root>` tag (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243443/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-for-angular2), specifically the comment by Christophe Vidal on the accepted answer).

This works fine, *however*, a problem arises if on app startup, the requested route happens to be one that corresponds to a route/module that is *lazy loaded*.

In that case, the spinner will initially display as expected, however will **disappear too early**. More specifically, when the spinner disappears, there still is noticeable time left before the actual content appears.

I assume this delay is due to the lazy loading and my spinner in `<app-root>` already being overwritten even though there is no content yet?

**index.html**

```
<app-root>
    <div class="loading">
        <!-- loading spinner here -->
    </div>
</app-root>
```

**How would you go about showing a loading spinner in this scenario?**

*Note: I am not asking about showing a spinner when getting data via http, I am asking about showing a spinner on startup of the app.*

Comment: I want to clarify your application architecture. On app startup the very first module that is routed to from your root is a lazy loaded module?

Comment: It depends on whatever route the user requests. But yes, there is a case where the very first module that is routed to is a lazy loaded module. And in that case, the spinner disappears too early. I assume what is happening is that it displays during app startup, but disappears as soon as control is transferred to the lazy loading so to speak. Hence while the lazy loading is going on, the spinner is already gone.

Comment: So perhaps a better title for my question would have been: "How to display a loading spinner during lazy loading"?

Comment: I think your title is clear. I just wanted to make sure you had other possible routes which may get loaded at the root during startup. Otherwise it wouldn't make much sense to use lazy loading if the only module that was loaded immediately is a lazy module, that would defeat the purpose of lazy loading.

Comment: Check out updated answer. I came across this technique while working and it reminded me of your issue.

Answer (score 2):

My take on this would be to subscribe to the Angular router events in your app root `app.component.ts` on initialization. However, it is important to note that this will not only result in your spinner being displayed while your lazy loaded component is loading, but also whenever you navigate to any route. (Which may not be what you desire)

```
ngOnInit(){
 router.events.subscribe( (event: Event) => {

            if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
                /*Display your spinner*/
            }

            if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
                /*Hide your spinner*/
            }
        });
}
```

### ***update***

I found you can bind to the `<router-outlet>` and that will allow you to determine what component is being loaded. I know the struggle was to get the spinner to only stop spinning once the lazy loaded component loads. By binding to the `router-outlet` in your `app.component.ts` you can determine what component is being loaded and at that point stop the spinner.

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<router-outlet #outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(RouterOutlet)
  public outlet: RouterOutlet;

  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.outlet.activateEvents.subscribe((component) => {
      if (component.__proto__.constructor.name === 'myLazyComponent') {
        //Hide Spinner
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are router [events](https://v5.angular.io/guide/router#router-events%22events%22): RouteConfigLoadStart and RouteConfigLoadEnd so the code would be:

```
import { Component, ViewChild, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<app-spinner *ngIf="showSpinner"></app-spinner><router-outlet></router-outlet>`
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  showSpinner: boolean = false;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
      this.router.events.subscribe(
              event => {
                if(event instanceof RouteConfigLoadStart) {
                  showSpinner = true;
                  return;
                }
                if(event instanceof RouteConfigLoadEnd) {
                  showSpinner = false;
                  return;
                }
          }
      );
   }
}
```

The app-spinner component can be some kind of overlay with spinning icon in the middle of browser window.