# to implement a spinner in angular2+

Tags: angular, spinner

I am trying to use a spinner in my application because there is lots of data that takes time to load. But here is the issue. I have taken this link as reference -

[Pre-Bootstrap Loading Screen For Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243443/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-for-angular2)

But the spinner keeps on and on and has occupied a fixed place in table body , it doesn't disappear as the data loads completely.  In the article above shown they have mentioned that using

```
 <app></app>
```

or

```
 <my-app></my-app> 

 (or probably 

 <app-root></app-root> 

  also)
```

Angular will automatically replace "Loading..." by the real content once Angular is loaded. However , this doesn't apply in my program. I have also used a boolean variable to hide when the variable is false. But to no avail.
Please check my code and guide accordingly.

**transaction.component.html**

```
 <table>
 <thead> ....
 </thead>

     <my-app>
      <div class="loaded" [class.loaded]="loaded">
      <div class="text-center">
       <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
        <div>Something witty for your userbase</div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </my-app>

  <tbody>
        .....
  </tbody>
   <table>
```

**transaction.component.ts**

```
 export class TransactionComponent implements OnInit {
 public loaded=false;


 ngOnInit() {

 this.loaded=true;


  }

 insideSearchByText(filterObj) {

    this.http.post("http://" + url + ":" + port + 
   "/transaction/masterSearchTransactionForm/", this.filterObj
      , { headers: new Headers({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + 
    localStorage.getItem('Token') }) })
   .map(result => this.result = result.json(),

    this.loaded=false)

    .subscribe((res: Response) => {
    ....
    }});
    }
```

**Error**

```
 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
 'my-app' is not a known element:
 1. If 'my-app' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part 
 of 
 this module.
 2. If 'my-app' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' 
 to 
 the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. 
 ("


  [ERROR ->]<my-app></my-app>
```

Comment: What styles are in the .loaded class?

Comment: no styles for .loaded.. i have used font awesome for spinner. loaded is a boolean variable i am using

Comment: [class.loaded]="loaded" means that if loaded is true, it adds the loaded class.

Comment: ohhh .. i thought if the loaded is true, then the div inside it will work. So do i need to add the css for loaded ??

Comment: Check out my answer. It should help. If not we can work on it some more. But if you don't have styles for loaded you don't need the class loaded. (Or maybe you do, it depends on the component implementation).

Comment: The error means you don't have <my-app> selector declared in your @Component meta data. Check and correct it.

Comment: It means i have to create another component ?? is it ?  because if i add it into  here --> transaction.component.ts --> @Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction',"my-app",  --> it gives error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="loaded" [class.loaded]="loaded" *ngIf="!loaded">
  <div class="text-center">
    <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
    <div>Something witty for your userbase</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can show the element only when the loading is occurring so `ngIf` should be enough.

If the loaded class doesn't contain anything, you probably don't need the wrapper. I don't know what styles are there.

Or post the link to the bootstrap component you are trying to use, if this is not enough for you.

Comment: Thank you laker .. but the thing is it only loads when i first load the page... after that ...when the page again comes back...it doesn't load  or show up even though i have written the loaded-true in ngOnInit ()

Comment: The ngIf shows and hides the element based on the boolean value. So everytime you start to load something, you have to set `this.loaded = false` and when it finishes `this.loaded = true`. ngOnInit happens once, when the component is created. So I guess in your case it would be `insideSearchByText(filterObj) { this.loaded = false; ... .subscribe((res: Response) => { this.loaded = true; ...`
I just now saw the error with my-app. It means you don't have that component in AppModule declarations array.

Comment: It means i have to create another component ?? is it ? because if i add it into here --> transaction.component.ts --> @Component({ selector: 'app-transaction',"my-app", --> it gives error –

Comment: You should create a new question with code example. We should talk here, in those small messages. Create question just with the error. Put code snippets from the @Component() decorators of those components and from AppModule. Post a link here and I'll take a look :)

Comment: ok i will create a new question ... but will this code work without <my-app> or <app-root> inside the decorator

Comment: If you want to have a component in a template, it has to have a selector. If you will only use it via routing, then it doesn't have to.  In decorator you should have 'my-app' without the <>. It's a selector, like CSS selector. And you can't have selectors for multiple components in one component decorator.

Comment: I didnot understand ...Please check ....https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50213811/component-giving-error-in-angular2