# @Component giving error in angular2+

Tags: angular, spinner

I am trying to use a spinner in my application because there is lots of data that takes time to load. But here is the issue. I have taken this link as reference -

[Pre-Bootstrap Loading Screen For Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243443/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-for-angular2)

and

[to implement a spinner in angular2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50211849/to-implement-a-spinner-in-angular2/50212368?noredirect=1#comment87443588_50212368)

In the article above shown they have mentioned that using   or   (or probably  also)  Angular will automatically replace "Loading..." by the real content once Angular is loaded. However , this doesn't apply in my program. 
Please check my code and guide accordingly.

**Error**

```
   Argument of type '{ selector: string; 'my-app': any; templateUrl: 
   string; styleUrls: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of 
   type 'Component'.
    Object literal may only specify known properties, and ''my-app'' 
   does not exist in type 'Component'.
```

**transaction.component.html**

```
 <table>
 <thead> ....
 </thead>

     <my-app>
      <div class="loaded" *ngIf="loaded">
      <div class="text-center">
       <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
        <div> Data Waiting To Be Loaded </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </my-app>

  <tbody>
        .....
  </tbody>
   <table>
```

**transaction.component.ts**

```
   @Component({
    selector: 'app-transaction','my-app',
    templateUrl: './transaction.component.html',
    styleUrls: 
     ['./transaction.component.scss',]

     }) 


 export class TransactionComponent implements OnInit {
 public loaded=false;


 ngOnInit() {

 this.loaded=true;


  }

 insideSearchByText(filterObj) {

    this.http.post("http://" + url + ":" + port + 
  .....

   .map(result => this.result = result.json(),

    this.loaded=false)


    ....
    }});
    }
```

**transaction.component.scss**

```
  .loaded {
   display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-transaction',
  templateUrl: './transaction.component.html',
  styleUrls: 
    ['./transaction.component.scss',]
})
```

Another component (if you have it):

```
@Component({
      selector: 'my-app',
      templateUrl: './my-app.component.html',
      styleUrls: 
        ['./my-app.component.scss',]
    })
export class MyAppComponent {
...
}
```

And in template use that selector:

```
<my-app>
  <div class="loaded" *ngIf="loaded">
    <div class="text-center">
      <i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin fa-3x fa-fw"></i>
      <div> Data Waiting To Be Loaded </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</my-app>
```

If you don't have the MyAppComponent, then you can't use it in template. Why do you have the  in the template?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a cyclic dependency because the typescript part tries to render the html and that would call the selector and this would end in an infinite loop?

Comment: I don't think I understand. <app-transaction> creates one instance of the component. Why would there be any infinite loop or cyclic dependency?

Comment: Yes but in this instance you call it again, like recursion. Or am i wrong? You can't call the component from its own html part?

Comment: Ah. It's in transaction component template. Sorry I didn't notice that. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: so laker .... <my-app> is another component... and its not compulsory to use it ...to make the spinner work ... ??

Comment: You don't need it if you dont have it :) The spinner doesn't have to be in any component. The div with class loaded is enough. You can just throw away the <my-app> wrapper. (If you didn't create it).

Comment: ok laker .. i am troubling you with yet another question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218158/how-to-implement-owldatetime-in-angular4-angular2

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is a syntax error. You have defined two selectors for this component. I think this line in your **transaction.component.ts**

```
selector: 'app-transaction','my-app',
```

should only be

```
selector: 'app-transaction',
```

since the selector doesn't take arrays as value (like e.g. styleUrls does).

Comment: then how to acknowledge "my-app"... do i need to create a new component altogether to use <my-app> in spinner  --> transaction.component.html

Comment: The tag to use for this component would be `<app-transaction>`

Comment: I want to know how do we access a different component  (like 'my-app')  in html of another component

Comment: You just use them like you did in the `html`. If you have a component with a selector: 'my-app' then you can use it. Do you have a component that has this selector?

Comment: Like in this link --> https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/    .. i want to use  Picker with rangeFrom and rangeTo selection .. so there it has a ts file. So to access that datetimepicker.. do i have to create  another component  (like ng g component  datetimepicker)??

Comment: i donot have a selector like that ...but when i use it just like an html it gives an error --> Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
 'my-app' is not a known element:

Comment: For sure, becuase you don't have that. The error message tells you exactly that. And your link about date-time-picker has nothing to do with your original question above

Comment: For the date-time-picker you should look here how to use it: https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker

Comment: because in this question also ..in the datetimepicker question ... it asks to create a ts if you have to use its html ... so i want to know  if here also  i should create another ts file .. a component altogether to make the datetimepicker work

Comment: No you need to import the modules in your app module and then you can use the selectors in every component you like. You don't need an extra component for that

Comment: hi ochs... the link you provided is for for Angular 6+ apps ...  i am using angular4 ...i also want to know how to update it .. and will it do any harm to my angular4 code

Comment: but the datetime picker i showed -->  https://danielykpan.github.io/date-time-picker/   has not module of its own...  it has an independent ts file.. isn't it ?

Comment: Yeah of course, because you need a component where you can use it. But you don't need an extra component for that. You can use it like there from every component you like. As you can see the ts file has nothing in it. It just provides the component so it can be used in angular

Comment: Hi ochs... i tried to implement from the link you provided...but the thing is it is giving version mismatch error ..
ERROR in Error: Metadata version mismatch for module /home/dell/Downloads/Datshare/Adaani5.0 (another copy).0/node_modules/ng-pick-datetime/picker.d.ts, found version 4, expected 3, resolving symbol MasterSystemModule in /home/dell/Downloads/Datshare/Adaani5.0 (another copy).0/src/app/master-system/master-system.module.ts, resolving symbol MasterSystemModule in /home/dell/Downloads/Datshare/Adaani5.0 (another copy).0/src/app/master-system/master-system.module.ts

Comment: I think you should open another question on this, cause it has nothing to do with the orginal question

Comment: hi ochs ... please check this link     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50218158/how-to-implement-owldatetime-in-angular4-angular2