# Angular Universal - How to preload?

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I have built an Angular App, which is now converted to an Angular Universal for the Server Side Rendering. However now, when the app loads it loads the UI first while it is still loading all the core .js files (main.1a23s..js)

Originally the preloading was overlaying the content perfectly, as described here - [Pre-Bootstrap Loading Screen For Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243443/pre-bootstrap-loading-screen-for-angular2) However this approach no longer seems to work?

Answer (score 1):

Hacky work around

```
// Listen for the event before bootstrapping:
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
    .then(()=>{
      console.log("LOADED")
      document.querySelector('.loading').classList.add('trans-out')
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
});
```