# How to set up a proper splash screen on Angular 6?

Tags: angular, splash-screen

Been trying to set up a Splash screen to show up before my login fully loads.
This is my 'login.component.html'.

```
<my-splash-page> </my-splash-page>
<div class="">
  <header >
    <ul>
      <li>
 ....
```

Now what the splash component should contain is what I'm clueless about, i've tried using some Subscription values but it doesn't quite work.

```
this.subscription = this.splashService.splashState
      .subscribe((state: LoaderState) => {
        this.show = state.show;
      });
```

The show variable should determine if it appears or not.

It's a somewhat fancy login so it'll take a couple of seconds to load the images but testing on 3G network I can clearly see the splash component dissapearing before the images in there fully or even start to load.

The splash screen shoud dissapear after everything is loaded (pictures, fonts, icons) but can't get it to work that way.

Comment: I think this is what you need https://stackoverflow.com/a/62526785/2877427

Answer (score 6):

Instead of adding in login.html, you can add  a div with splashscreen class which will display splashscreen image inside **index.html**.

```
<div class="splashScreenClass" id="splashScreenClass">
    <h1>Loading...</h1>
</div>
```

**In app.component.ts**

You can remove from the DOM.

```
ngOnInit(){
  const splashScreen: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('splashScreenClass');
    if (splashScreen) {
      splashScreen.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: So I'm trying adding the splash into the login instead of a separate component and also I should attempt removing it from the app.component.ts?

Comment: Content in index.html will be loaded first. It's good option to add it there. You can create a seprate component or 'div'. It's up to you. Make sire it got removed in app.component.ts

Comment: A mate told me to use window.onload and then I felt pretty silly... Although one of my seniors told me that I should look for an Angular alternative since window.onload is pure javascript and it ain't a good fix, is this how you meant that I gotta remove it on app.component.ts?, I got to use the code above but what it does is that it inmediatly removes the element and it doesn't show at all.