# Angular - How to show waiting indicator while app is loading using APP_INITIALIZER

Tags: angular

How to show waiting indicator when angular app is executing app_initializer code.

As of now I can show waiting indicator till app is loaded. But after that page stays empty till app_initializer code is complete. So I want to show some sort of waiting indicator.

```
<app-root>Loading....</app-root>
```

Also Tried

```
<app-root></app-root>
<div>Loading...</div>
```

None of these option work when app_initializer is executing.... during this time period I am calling web api to get some startup data.

Comment: Elaborate on what you tried so far! Posting code?

Comment: Particularly for API calls, If you want to show indicator, I suggest you should use
https://github.hubspot.com/pace/docs/welcome/

And for other operations/executions you can use:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-loading

Comment: I had the same issue and finally I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35244932).

Answer (score 2):

Below worked for me:

```
<style>
    .loader {
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    border: 16px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top: 16px solid #3498db;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
    }
    @keyframes spin {
    0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    }
    100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    }
    }
</style>

<app-root>
      <div class="loader"></div>
</app-root>
```

Comment: Try to explain what you have done, instead of just posting code, give OP a chance to understand what you are doing. 
And this looks a lot like the one thing that he already tried, with some animations instead of just "loading..."

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correctly what are you trying to achieve, you should check on app.component if APP_INITIALIZER is done.
The ApplicationInitStatus expose status of APP_INITIALIZER which you can check using donePromise.

So i will get Injection Token in app.component.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: []
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnInit {

  constructor(
    @Inject(APP_INITIALIZER) public appInit: ApplicationInitStatus
  ) { ... }

  ngOnInit () {...}
}
```

And in app.component.html check if APP_INITIALIZER is done using donePromise and async pipe:

```
<ng-container *ngIf="!(appInit.donePromise | async)"> Loading... </ng-container>
```

Comment: Thanks Marack for your reply, I applied this code and checked but it still doesnt solve my problem since, appCoponent is only getting initialized when APP_INITIALIZER code is completed.

To Check this I specifically added time delay of 10 seconds in app_initializer code and found that, "Loading..." message appears after those 10 seconds has elapsed.

Comment: I tried that, but I thing he make a mistake, instead of adding the ng-container above that contains the Loading... text, you have to add it inside the index.html file, exactly inside the <app-root> </app-root> component. and it should work correctly.